# SQL count across 2 tables with composite primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to return the rows from Table1 where the composite key from Table1 exists more than say 2 times in Table 2.

My attempt which fails:

```
 SELECT 
     t 
 FROM 
     Table1 t, Table2 m
 WHERE 
     t.brand = m.brand AND t.model = m.model
 GROUP BY 
     m.brand, m.model 
 HAVING 
     COUNT(m.brand) > 2
```

Expected rows returned:

```
--------------------------------
brand  | model | color | price | 
--------------------------------
toyota |   R   |   r   |  25   |
```

Tables:

Table1

```
--------------------------------------
brand     |  model    | color | price | 
--------------------------------------
toyota    |     R     |   r   |  25   |
ford      |     T     |   y   |  40   |
chevy     |     X     |   b   |  10   |
```

Table2

```
------------------------
brand      | model     |
------------------------
toyota     |     R     |
ford       |     T     |
chevy      |     X     |
toyota     |     R     |
toyota     |     R     |
chevy      |     X     |
```

Comment: which db server platform do you use?

Comment: jpql/oracle...........

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

You can get the combinations that appear more than twice using `group by`:

```
SELECT m.brand, m.model
FROM Table1 t 
GROUP BY m.brand, m.model 
HAVING COUNT(m.brand) > 2;
```

You can get the corresponding rows from table1 using various techniques.  Here is the `exists` method:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Table1 t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table2 m
              WHERE t.brand = m.brand AND t.model = m.model
              GROUP BY m.brand, m.model
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
             );
```

EDIT:

In Oracle, you can use window functions.  That is the simplest way:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.brand, t.model) as cnt
      FROM Table1 t JOIN
           Table2 m
           ON t.brand = m.brand AND t.model = m.model
     ) tm
WHERE cnt > 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I used the exists method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this simplified [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32186/5), I've changed the join.

```
SELECT m.brand, m.model  
 FROM T1 t INNER JOIN T2 m
 ON t.brand = m.brand AND t.model = m.model
 GROUP BY m.brand, m.model 
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```